# The Direct Sum in The Definition of Tensor Algebra

Tags: tensor-products, tensors, direct-sum, algebras

In the definition of the tensor algebra associated with the vector space $V$ over a field $\Bbbk$,
$$
T(V)= \bigoplus_{k=0}^{\infty} V^{\otimes k}
$$
writing it all out we get
$$
T(V)= \Bbbk \oplus V \oplus (V \otimes V) \oplus (V \otimes V \otimes V) \oplus \cdots \oplus (V \otimes \cdots \otimes V) \oplus \cdots.
$$

In this definition, the direct sum is between different objects, namely $\Bbbk \oplus V \oplus (V\otimes V) \oplus \cdots$ etc. However, I cannot find any sources explaining how this would work, could someone help me with this definition?

My sources are https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_algebra and "An Introduction to Clifford Algebras and Spinors by Jayme Vazz, Roldão da Rocha."

Comment: Your typeset math looked horrifically bad and did not compile at all.  Read over the edited version above to check it is what you meant (and please look at the code to see how to typeset math correctly).

Comment: The last section of https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod2.pdf discusses the tensor algebra of a module over a commutative ring. This includes the tensor algebra of a vector space by letting the ring $R$ be a field $\Bbb k$: $\Bbb k$-modules are the same as $\Bbb k$-vector spaces. The tensor algebra is Definition 8.4  and earlier results in that section set up the multiplication, but perhaps it will not make sense to you. The main idea is to "multiply" elements tensors in $V^{\otimes p}$ and $V^{\otimes q}$ by concatenating things together to lie in $V^{\otimes (p+q)}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a family of $k$-vector spaces $\{V_i\}_{i \in I}$, the *direct sum* $$V := \bigoplus_{i \in I} V_i$$ is defined to be the set of all functions $\alpha : I \to \bigcup_{i \in I} V_i$ such that $\alpha_i := \alpha(i) \in V_i$ for all $i \in I$, and that $\{i \in I : \alpha_i \neq 0\}$ is a finite set. Note that each $V_j$ can be naturally embedded in $V$ by identifying $v_j \in V_j$ with the function $v \in V$ such that $v_i = 0$ for all $i \neq j$. Thus, we write $\alpha \in V$ as a finite sum $\alpha = \sum_{i \in I} \alpha_i$.

Therefore, for example, $1 + v \otimes v + v \otimes v \otimes v \otimes v \in T(V)$ for $v \in V$.

Comment: Thank you! Thinking of the direct sum as a function helped me associate it.